# ffmpeg dynamic filter values from piped input

Tags: ffmpeg, audio, filter, metadata

I need to run an audio filter on a piped input using its own lufs value as a variable, without writing to disk.

I previously bounced the piped input to `processedaudio.wav` and the command works as:

```
ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -af $(echo "startofafilter$(echo "$(
ffmpeg -i processedaudio.wav -vn -af ebur128=framelog=verbose -f null - 2>&1 |awk '/I:/{print $2}')")
restofthefilter") -f null - 2>&1);
```

which pulls the lufs value from `processedaudio.wav` in that nested ffmpeg command (which is the same as pipe:0), but the value needs to change dynamically with each file. I need it to read from the pipe (or whatever gets me a similar effect) like this:

```
ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -af $(echo "startofafilter$(echo "$(
ffmpeg -i pipe:0 -vn -af ebur128=framelog=verbose -f null - 2>&1 |awk '/I:/{print $2}')")
restofthefilter") -f null - 2>&1);
```

where the only change is the nested input, but that command just hangs. Any ideas?

Edit: This is basically the workflow needed:
[image]

Edit2: Attempting a named pipe seems to cause ffmpeg to hang.
Named pipes are working in general:

```
mkfifo outpipe.wav | ffmpeg -y -i test.mov outpipe.wav | ffmpeg -f wav -i outpipe.wav testout.wav
```

and this command works with an actual file name:

```
echo "$(ffmpeg -f wav -i test.wav -vn -af "ebur128=framelog=verbose" -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/I:/{print $2}')"
```

But it doesn't work with a piped input:

```
mkfifo outpipe.wav | ffmpeg -y -i test.mov outpipe.wav | echo "$(ffmpeg -f wav -i outpipe.wav -vn -af "ebur128=framelog=verbose" -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/I:/{print $2}')"
```

At this point, I'm not sure what's going on. Am I missing something? Is this a bug?

Comment: How are you planning to use the LUFS value?

Comment: I'm doing some math to it and using that new number as the adjustment value for the audio filter. The files I process have different average levels in every video, mostly voice over at a constant level within each video, so the value must be adjusted up or down as needed.

Comment: It will eventually be the n value for silencedetect, if that helps.

Comment: Make the pipe input available though two named pipes and read through those..